# ZF2 paginator performance with fetchAll without limit?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-paginator

Most of cases **in ZF2** I would do a paginator like this:

```
public function fetchAll()
{
 $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select();
 return $resultSet;
}

$iteratorAdapter = new \Zend\Paginator\Adapter\Iterator($this->getSampleTable()->fetchAll());
$paginator = new \Zend\Paginator\Paginator($iteratorAdapter);
```

**The problem of this aproch is that It is not limiting the query result, and fetchAll returns all the results (producing big trafic between db and php).**

**In pure php** I would do a pagination like this:

```
$PAGE_NUM = $_GET['page_num'];
$result_num = mysq_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE some condition");
$result = mysq_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE some condition LIMIT $PAGE_NUM, 20");
echo do_paginator($result_num, 20, $PAGE_NUM);//THIS JUST MAKE THE CLASSIC < 1 2 3 4 5 >
```

The advantage of this is that I fetch from the DB only the data I need in the pagination thanks to LIMIT option in mysql. This is translate in good performance on query that returns too much records.

**Can I use the ZF2 paginator with a effective limit to the results, or I need to make my own paginator?**

Comment: use the `Zend\Paginator\Adapter\DbSelect` adapter instead. http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/release-2.1.4/modules/zend.paginator.usage.html#the-dbselect-adapter

Comment: I am reading it now, it seems to be my solution:**..Additionally this adapter does not fetch all records from the database..**

Comment: that's right, it does exactly what you're asking for, applying limit and offset to the query you give it to begin with, and just fetching those records.

Comment: put that as answer I will accept that. put this phrase:Additionally this adapter does not fetch all records from the database in order to count them. Instead, the adapter manipulates the original query to produce a corresponding COUNT query. Paginator then executes that COUNT query to get the number of rows. This does require an extra round-trip to the database, but this is many times faster than fetching an entire result set and using count(), especially with large collections of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Zend\Paginator\Adapter\DbSelect`](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/release-2.1.4/modules/zend.paginator.usage.html#the-dbselect-adapter) adapter instead, it does exactly what you're asking for, applying limit and offset to the query you give it to begin with, and just fetching those records.

> Additionally this adapter does not fetch all records from the database in order to count them. Instead, the adapter manipulates the original query to produce a corresponding COUNT query. Paginator then executes that COUNT query to get the number of rows. This does require an extra round-trip to the database, but this is many times faster than fetching an entire result set and using count(), especially with large collections of data.